# Log4j logs to show in allure report

Tags: java, logging, log4j, testng, allure

I'm trying to show logj4 logs in allure report, there are different ways to do it and i want to find the best solution.

As an option I can create something like this:

```
public class AllureLogger {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AllureLogger.class);

    public static void info(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
        attachLogToAllure("INFO: " + message);
    }

    public static void error(String message) {
        logger.error(message);
        attachLogToAllure("ERROR: " + message);
    }

    @Attachment(value = "{logMessage}", type = "text/plain")
    private static String attachLogToAllure(String logMessage) {
        return logMessage;
    }
}
```

But maybe there are more appropriate ways to do it. I didn't find any libraries for log4j - allure integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AllureLifecycle to modify your current test case / test step. Also, you can use listeners to modify the allure after test failed (e.g. TestNG listener).

```
@Log4j2
public class TestListener extends AllureTestNg {
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult testResult) {
        log.debug("Running test method: {}",testResult.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }
 }
```

Also you don't need to create logger instance, instead you can used annotation @Log4j or @Log4j2 above the class (but pay attention to the package).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure log4j to also log to a separate file per test, then attach whole file to the report.

Step by step setup:

- add routing appender to log4j2 configuration:

```yaml
    Routing:
      - name: Test
        Routes:
          pattern: '$${ctx:uuid}'
          Route:
            RollingFile:
              immediateFlush: true
              append: false
              name: 'RollingFile-${ctx:uuid}'
              fileName: '${logDir}/test-${ctx:uuid}.log'
              filePattern: '${logDir}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/archived_%d{HH-mm}-${ctx:uuid}.log'
              PatternLayout:
                pattern: '%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
              Policies:
                - OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
```

- create listener class

```java
public class AllureTestListener implements TestLifecycleListener {
    protected static final String LOG_PATH = "build/logs/";
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> TL_TEST_UUID = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final String LOG_FILE_PATTERN = "test-%s.log";
    private final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void afterTestStart(TestResult result) {
        startTestLogging();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestStop(TestResult result) {
        stopTestLogging();
    }

    private void startTestLogging() {
        TL_TEST_UUID.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ThreadContext.put("uuid", TL_TEST_UUID.get());
    }

    private void stopTestLogging() {
        ThreadContext.remove("uuid");

        String logFileName = String.format(LOG_FILE_PATTERN, TL_TEST_UUID.get());
        File logFile = Paths.get(LOG_PATH, logFileName).toFile();
        addLogAttachment(logFile);
    }

    private void addLogAttachment(File logFile) {
        try {
            Allure.addAttachment("Log", new FileInputStream(
                    logFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(String.format("There is no log file %s", logFile.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

- add listener to your listeners

In log4j2 configuration we have a routing appender, which logs to separate file per uuid context property. AllureTestListener controls uuid on per-thread basis(to support parallel tests run), by putting test uuid into TL_TEST_UUID thread-local variable in `afterTestStart` method. Then, before test stops, we remove that variable, and attach log file to the report.